# FontAwesome center icons horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my scenario:

I have 4 `bootstrap's` `col-md-3` where each of them has a `fontawesome` icon that I want to center horizontally. However, what I'm currently doing, doesn't work.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
.social-badge a{
    display: inline-block;
}

.social-badge a .fa{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18nr4acu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to text-align the container div:

```
social-badge a{
    display: inline-block;
}

.social-badge {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please next time paste your CSS in the CSS box, rather than into the javascript's :)

Answer (score 1):

> [**MDN - Text-align**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)
>
> The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element.

Therefore `text-align: center` must be on the parent element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xb0u0LL/)

```
.social-badge {
    text-align: center;
}
.social-badge a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants the text down a bit and the icons up a bit. Not everything center. Much respect to you Crozier.

Comment: he wants to center them *horizontally*. The fiddle is misleading since that little iframe shows the 'mobile' version, not the desktop one.